# Siphon NCSS returns nan values

Tags: metpy, python-siphon

I'm trying to plot latest HRRR surface temperature with data from the THREDDS data server.

```
cat = TDSCatalog('https://thredds-test.unidata.ucar.edu/thredds/catalog/'
                 'grib/NCEP/HRRR/CONUS_2p5km/latest.xml')
dataset = cat.datasets[0]
ncss = dataset.subset()

sfctemp = ncss.query()
sfctemp.variables('Temperature_height_above_ground')
sfctemp.vertical_level(2.0)
sfctemp.add_lonlat().lonlat_box(north=55, south=20, east=281, west=230)
sfctemp.time(now)
sfctemp_data = ncss.get_data(sfctemp)
```

That works fine, however, when I grab and print the actual data values from:

```
sfctemp_vars = units.K * sfctemp_data.variables['Temperature_height_above_ground'][:].squeeze()
```

It returns:

```
[[nan nan nan ... nan nan nan] [nan nan nan ... nan nan nan] [nan nan nan ... nan nan nan] ... [nan nan nan ... nan nan nan] [nan nan nan ... nan nan nan] [nan nan nan ... nan nan nan]] kelvin
```

Not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong here. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's actually a problem going on. If I run your code, I do see what you see:

```
[[nan nan nan ... nan nan nan] [nan nan nan ... nan nan nan] [nan nan nan ... nan nan nan] ... [nan nan nan ... nan nan nan] [nan nan nan ... nan nan nan] [nan nan nan ... nan nan nan]] kelvin
```

These are just missing values where the grid has undefined/missing values along the edges of the domain. If I run:

```
import numpy as np
np.nanmax(sfctemp_vars)
```

I get:

```
308.1873
```

A quick plot with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(sfctemp_vars)
```

gives me something that seems reasonable:

[image: Data image plot]

Note the patches of white missing data at the top and bottom.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks much, turns out the error I was getting was related to the way I was converting the Kelvin to F, which was wrong and I incorrectly pointed it to the nan values and hence the bbox error message (which maybe would’ve helped if I put in the original post). Thanks!